# Adding one last row to DevExpress GridControl from a query

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a dataset filled by SQL query..
I want to add a single row to its last rows, containing sum from the value column..

Could u help me? thx...

Regards,
Roland

Answer (score 2):

The GridControl is able to show and calculate footer summary itself.  To learn how to adjust  the grid, please refer to the [Summaries](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3502) and [Total Summary](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument699) topics

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. i've been trying in my code, but still the SUM didn't want to show in footer cell... Here is my case : I filled the dataset with a query, let's just say "SELECT * FROM Master", which have ID, NAME, PRICE columns.. i want to add manually the SUM FOOTER CELL below the PRICE columns..

Comment: To be able to help you, I need to know the code you wrote.  Please post it here.